# Issue while creating primary key from gorm model

Tags: go, primary-key, go-gorm, cockroachdb

While creating primary key from gorm model it return with error “duplicate column name: “id””

my model looks like

```
type User struct { 
gorm.Model 
Id string gorm:"primary_key;" 
FirstName string 
LastName string 
}
```

any idea what is the issue with above model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gorm uses [`ID`](https://gorm.io/docs/conventions.html#ID-as-Primary-Key) as the primary key by default. It is [part of](https://gorm.io/docs/conventions.html#gorm-Model) the `gorm.Model` you are embedding.

When embedding the `gorm.Model`, you should leave `ID` out as gorm already includes it. The alternative is to remove the embedded `gorm.Model` and specify `ID` yourself.

To quote the [gorm conventions](https://gorm.io/docs/conventions.html#gorm-Model) page:

> gorm.Model is a basic GoLang struct which includes the following
>   fields: ID, CreatedAt, UpdatedAt, DeletedAt.
>
> It may be embeded into your model or you may build your own model
>   without it.

The reasons this fails on schema creation as opposed to compilation is that a lot of databases (CockroachDB included) do case insensitive checking unless you quote the object names (`Id` matches `id`, but `"Id"` does not). This results in two separate column names that match when compared with case insensitivity.